# Undetermined parameters: system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the inhomogeneous system: $$y'-\left[ \begin{matrix}1 &2\\3 &6\end{matrix} \right]y=\left[ \begin{matrix}0\\ \cos{x}\end{matrix} \right]$$

I have already found the solution to the homogenoeus problem, however, I need to know how can I choose the particular solution $y_p$ to match the inomogeneous part and solve the matrix problem by undetermined coefficients.

Thanks in advance.

PS. Does 'undetermined parameters' mean the same as 'undetermined coefficients'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's undetermined coefficients.  If you are comfortable with complex numbers, look for solutions of $y' - \left[\matrix{1 & 2\cr 3 & 6\cr}\right] y = \left[\matrix{0\cr e^{ix}\cr}\right]$ of \the form $e^{ix} {\bf v}$ where $\bf v$ is a constant vector, and take the real part.  If not, try $\cos(x) {\bf v}  + \sin(x) {\bf w}$.

Comment: I tried the second option already but I wonder if in the first row I should pick a regular unknown for the 0 $\begin{matrix} 0 \\ A \cos{x} + B\sin{x} \end{matrix}$, in that case I get a system of 2 equations for 2 unknowns.